# Django path didn’t match any of these when adding query param to the endpoint

Tags: django, url, endpoint, query-string, django-rest-viewsets

I am using django 4.1

I have a product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name="stock ID",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    availability = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="product availability")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

product/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("product/<slug:product_id>", productViewset, basename="productPrice")
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

and in project urls.py

```
api_patterns = [
    path("", include("product.urls")),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include(api_patterns)),
]
```

when I try to call this endpoint"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/2048cf23-6bb2-4532-a140-b13dd1361c4/" it doesn't match any of the paths in my project!

NB:product_id is not the primary key as there are more than one row for the same product but at different time and price.

I tried to use < str:product_id > < string:product_id >  < uuid:product_id > but nothing works,I am not sure why it's happening but when I change the url in product urls.py to `router.register("product", productViewset, basename="productPrice")` it works but I need to path that id to filter the queryset.

the error message

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/2048cf23-6bb2-4532-a140-b13dd1361c4/
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/ ^product/<slug:product_id>//$ [name='productPrice-list']
api/ ^product/<slug:product_id>\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='productPrice-list']
api/ ^product/<slug:product_id>//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='productPrice-detail']
api/ ^product/<slug:product_id>//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='productPrice-detail']
api/ ^$ [name='api-root']
api/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
api/ ^$ [name='api-root']
api/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
The current path, api/product/2048cf23-6bb2-4532-a140-b13dd1361c4/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: Try to give closing `/` at the end of url, `"product/<slug:product_id>/"`

Comment: I did but still same error